# Electron packaging with electron-packager

Tags: packaging, electron

I am trying to package my app using electron-packager. Below is my code.

```
electron-packager ./electron Myapp --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.34.0 --overwrite
```

i added folder named electron to my app and to my surprise, Myapp is always packaged to my parent folder . It does not recognise the electron folder despite the fact that the folder is available.

Moreover, when my app is packaged, it shows my app icon, version and licence files in the finder. But from my code editor, it shows the folder has many files and subfolders like below,

[image] .

The above folder when viewed from finder, it displays only licence, version and my exe . This however happened only in darwin platform. Please what am i doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Note , i am running an OSX operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.apps are technically just folders. Your editor is taking that into account and showing the contents. If you right click on your app, and press show package contents, you'll see whats inside the app. Also, electron-packager does not support outputting to a different directory. You could however `cd electron` and run electron packager from there, and then it would package to that directory. EDIT: you can actually output to a different directory, with the --out option.

Comment: the show package contents does not appear among the options . So i can't access the folder .

Comment: @NuruSalihu are you looking from the finder app? Also, it's a .app right?

Comment: yes its .app willy. I was only able to acces the folder after renaming which destroy the app because when you name, your .exe disappear.

Comment: @NuruSalihu I have just discovered that there was a --out option for electron-pakager so you could run the command like so: `electron-packager ./electron Myapp --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite --out=./electron`. Give that a try and report back :) Also, sorry for slow reply, was sleeping lol! Edit: [heres](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt) something else you might find useful for electron packager.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in package.JSON

```
"scripts": { 

"start": "electron .",
 "install": "electron-rebuild",

 "package-osx": "electron-packager . Node-RED --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --out=build --overwrite",

"package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds",

 "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"CryptoApp\"",

 "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds" 

},

 "dependencies": {

 "electron-packager": "^12.1.0",

 "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",

 }
```

In case of no working for windows use following...

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"CryptoApp\"",
```

Thanks...